# Qt: Can child objects be composed in their parent object?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qobject

In Qt, can I embed child widgets in their parent via composition, or do I have to create them with `new`?

```
class MyWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    ...
private:
    QPushButton myButton;
}

MyWindow::MyWindow ()
 : mybutton("Do Something", this)
{
   ...
}
```

The documentation says that any object derived from `QObject` will automatically destroyed when its parent is destroyed; this implies a call to `delete`, whcih in the above example would crash.

Do I have to use the following?

```
QPushButton* myButton;

myButton = new QPushButton("Do Something", this);
```

**EDIT**

The answers are quite diverse, and basically boil down to three possibilities:

- **Yes**, composition is ok. Qt can figure out how the object was allocated and only `delete` heap-allocated objects (How does this work?)
- **Yes**, composition is ok, but don't specify a parent, since the parent would otherwise call `delete` on the object (But won't a parent-less widget turn into a top-level window?)
- **No**, widgets always have to be heap-allocated.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The non-static, non-heap member variables are deleted when that particular object's delete sequence starts. Only when all members are deleted, will it go to the destructor of the base class. Hence QPushButton myButton member will be deleted before ~QMainWindow() is called. And from QObject documentation: "If we delete a child object before its parent, Qt will automatically remove that object from the parent's list of children". Hence no crash will occur.

Comment: Your answer is almost correct, but the order of Destruction is incorrect. See e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8183zf3x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

[Object trees & ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html) answers your question. Basically when the child object is created on the heap it will be deleted by its parent.

On the other hand when the child object is created on the stack the order of destruction is important. The child will be destroyed **before** its parent and will remove itself from its parent's list so that its destructor is not called twice.

There is also an example in that link that shows problematic order of destruction.

Comment: So, if we have (either stack or heap) composite and it is destructed (either via `delete` or when the stack object's lifetime ends), firstly the composite's destructor is called (and does whatever it wants to do, but not removes anything from its children, as this logic is implemented within QObject), then the composite's children/members get destructed (with their destructors called) and remove themselves from what still remains from the object (again using the QObject functionality), and only then the QObject's destructor is finally called, and sees no children -- hence no double delete.

Answer (score 4):

> The documentation says that any object derived from QObject will automatically destroyed when its parent is destroyed; **this implies a call to delete**

No. It implies **a call to the destructor** of that particular entity.

Say in your example, if `MyWindow` is destroyed, it means the destructor of the `MyWindow` has been called. Which in turn will call the destructor `myButton` which is implemented already in `QPushButton`.

If you have composite entity, just the destructor will be called on that entity but not `delete` and so it won't crash.

Parent child relationships in Qt doesn't require specifically to be in a stack or heap.  It can be in anything.

A similar example in parent child relationship over a stack is over [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html#construction-destruction-order-of-qobjects).

HTH..

Comment: How does the parent know whether the child is heap-allocated or not? As I understand it, calling a destructor does not free the heap space occupied by the object (`delete` is required for that) -- or am I wrong?

Comment: @ Jen, Yes. If it is allocated thro `new`, you have to `delete` it. I assume it is by the Qt meta object system that the application is able to identify the child's allocation.. Couldn't find any docs regarding that. Will update if I find something..

Comment: @ Jen, But is won't crash. You tried that? It dint crash right?

Comment: Attempting to `delete` a composited or stack-allocated object might not crash an application, but it can lead to heap corruption and undefined behavior.

Comment: The parent does not know whether a child is heap-allocated or not. But a QObject removes itself from the children list of its parent in its destructor.

Answer (score 2):

The object will be destroyed only when it has a parent pointer, so you can use:

```
MyWindow::MyWindow ()
 : mybutton("Do Something", 0)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: If a `QWidget` is parent-less, won't it turn into a top-level window?

Comment: Yes, this is true. If you want a QWidget  to be a child of another QWidget you have to give the parent which implies that you have to create it on the heap. But there are other QObject-derived classes where it makes sense to use them as member variables.

Comment: -1: More for your comment than your actual answer. As other people have pointed out there is no implication at all that a `QObject` must on the heap just because it has a parent.

Comment: Your downvote is unjustified. From the documentation of QObject::~QObject(): "Warning: All child objects are deleted. If any of these objects are on the stack or global, sooner or later your program will crash." Heap objects only work when it is guaranteed that the destructor of the child is finished before the destructor of the parent (see link in the answer of OrcunC).

Answer (score 0):

You should create it on heap, since QObject will destroy it :

```
class MyWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    ...
private:
    QPushButton *myButton;
}

MyWindow::MyWindow ()
 : mybutton( new QPushButton( "Do Something", this) )
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: -1: As others have pointed out there is no need to create it on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

calling `delete` operator will not crash ur application, you can read the following quote

> Qt's parent–child mechanism is implemented in QObject. When we create an object (a widget, validator, or any other kind) with a parent, the parent adds the object to the list of its children. When the parent is deleted, it walks through its list of children and deletes each child. The children themselves then delete all of their children, and so on recursively until none remain. The parent–child mechanism greatly simplifies memory management, reducing the risk of memory leaks. The only objects we must call delete on are the objects we create with new and that have no parent. And if we delete a child object before its parent, Qt will automatically remove that object from the parent's list of children.

note that the parent argument is `NULL` by default (default argument) 
this is QPushButton Constructor

```
QPushButton ( const QString & text, QWidget * parent = 0 )
```

so u can use

```
    MyWindow::MyWindow () : mybutton( new QPushButton( "Do Something") ){   ... }
```

and u can call `delete` on any component and any time

Qt will take care for this point

Answer (score 0):

Let me just [quote the source](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp) here.

```
816 QObject::~QObject()
817 {
818     Q_D(QObject);
819     d->wasDeleted = true;
820     d->blockSig = 0; // unblock signals so we always emit destroyed()
821 
   ...
924 
925     if (!d->children.isEmpty())
926         d->deleteChildren();
927 
928     qt_removeObject(this);
929 
930     if (d->parent)        // remove it from parent object
931         d->setParent_helper(0);
932 
933 #ifdef QT_JAMBI_BUILD
934     if (d->inEventHandler) {
935         qWarning("QObject: Do not delete object, '%s', during its event handler!",
936                  objectName().isNull() ? "unnamed" : qPrintable(objectName()));
937     }
938 #endif
939 }

    ...

1897 void QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren()
1898 {
1899     const bool reallyWasDeleted = wasDeleted;
1900     wasDeleted = true;
1901     // delete children objects
1902     // don't use qDeleteAll as the destructor of the child might
1903     // delete siblings
1904     for (int i = 0; i < children.count(); ++i) {
1905         currentChildBeingDeleted = children.at(i);
1906         children[i] = 0;
1907         delete currentChildBeingDeleted;
1908     }
1909     children.clear();
1910     currentChildBeingDeleted = 0;
1911     wasDeleted = reallyWasDeleted;
1912 }
```

So as you can see, `QObject` does indeed `delete` each of its children in the destructor. In addition, the destructor is executed [*before*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8183zf3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) destructors of any members; so if the composite in question equals the parent – then member `QObject` won't have any chance to remove itself from the children list of its parent.

This, unfortunately, means that you **cannot** compose a `QObject` into *its parent*. But you can compose into other objects, as well as allocate on stack – as soon as you guarantee to destruct the object or reset its parent to 0 *before* the parent starts destructing.